# Windows 10 Error code 0xc000001 - Recovery: Your PC Couldn't Start Properly

Tags: windows-10, boot, reboot

Situation:
this happens when rebooting:

```
Error code 0xc000001 - Recovery: Your PC Couldn't Start Properly
```

(blue screen)

I have two options: either enter UEFI setting or try again. 
When I hit <kbd>F5</kbd> (try again), sometimes it succeeds at first try, other times, I need to try for 1-3 times. But, in the end, it boots. Strange? SSD, bitlocker turned on.

Comment: When you say "it boots" you are getting to the Windows login screen?

Comment: yes, after I get past the 'error' everything works perfectly fine. I did run chkdsk on the partition. There's an EFI System Parition (260mb), recovery partition (449MB) and the main Boot parition on which Windows is located. Then there's one magnetic drive, - beside the SSD in question.

Comment: I wouldn't want to reformat again as I've spent some time already setting up VS, Eclipse, VPNs and some other stuff. If it helps, I reformated the drive, due to a lost Bitlocker recovery key. Bitlocker locked my drive after an.... windows update; so yeah - a funny week with a MS product.

Comment: really no-one has an idea? It might have something to do with TPM module since windows was not able to take ownership. I have cleared it though.

Answer (score 0):

Well.. what I did was... Put a Windows 8.1 installation DVD.. and waited... For the hanging cuz it was slow and continue on clicking next slowly cuz it was hanging.. (u can play on the phone and wait for the hanging to progress) then click custom installation and when u see a list of selective drive u wanna install... Format all the inbuilt drive (well I put my files on an external drive so I don't really give a damn about formatting the inbuilt)... It will really hang but if u want it to work.. then u must have the patience to wait.... After formatting all the inbuilt drive... install the windows u wanna.. and it'll work...

Comment: Are you saying this is a disk formatting issue? That if OP can format the drive it'll install properly? Your awkward formatting makes it difficult to understand exactly what you are saying. Please use the edit button to improve your answer and make it both more legible and more informative.

Comment: I have this issue after virtualizing a physical drive with Windows 10 UEFI bootable. It boots afterwards, but still have to wait a couple of minutes. Weird, I know..